# Display function in pyspark shows less records

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe, which gives me 6 recs when I am displaying values for a particular column, but shows 5 recs when displayed as a whole. Not able to figure out the reason.

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM fin WHERE __file_name__ = 'MAT1_2022_07.csv' and  RefDocNo LIKE '360237588%'")

df.column("RefDocNo").display() --Gives 6 recs

df.display() --Gives 5 recs.
```

Pls note: df.count() gives 6 recs. Also tried df.display(n=df.count()), but still seeing 5 recs

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes. I am running the pyspark in databricks

Comment: Does it say "truncated data" at the end of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has some limitations on `display` function (unfortunately I can't find the exact spec). By default it should show up to 10,000 records. But, if one or some of your columns has a really long string, then this 10,000 is reduced to some smaller numbers. So try to identify which long string column you have, try to drop that before display, you'll see all of your data.